# Error:sorry, unimplemented: string literal in function template signature while Using decltype in function template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, decltype

Hi i am trying to understand how templates work and trying out different examples. I am getting an error while executing the code below. First i am writing the code and then will write what i think is happening.

**Code snippet 1**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>

template<typename It>
auto fcn(It beg, It end) -> decltype(*beg +"name"){ //why isn't decltype(*beg + "name") working here??
    
    return *beg;
}
int main()
{   
    std::vector<std::string> stringVector = {"firstElement","secondElement"};
    std::vector<std::string>::iterator beg = stringVector.begin();
    
    decltype(*beg + "k") l = "anothername";//this is okay and is working here.
    
    
    std::string s = fcn(stringVector.begin(), stringVector.end());
   
  
   return 0;
}
```

While compiling/executing snippet 1 i get an error.

> sorry, unimplemented: string literal in function template signature
> auto fcn(It beg, It end) -> decltype(*beg +"name"){

Here is my explanation of what is happening: The return type of the function template fcn will be deduced from the expression `decltype(*beg + "name")`. So `*beg` is a reference to the element and in our case `*beg` is a reference to string that is `string&` and then `*beg + "name"` is a rvalue string. So decltype(*beg + "name") will give us a type `string`. But inside the definition of the function template fcn we are returning string& and therefore the return type of the function(string) and the type of the value returned from the function(string&) does not match and we get the error. But now as in the 2nd Code snippet i replace `return *beg;` with `std::string temp = "name"; return temp;` the return type and the type of the returned value should match. The problem is in the 2nd case i am still getting an error. Why am i getting this error and how can i resolve this? Also is my explanation of what is going on correct?

**Code Snippet 2**:

```
auto fcn(It beg, It end) -> decltype(*beg +"name"){ //why isn't decltype(*beg + "name") working here??
    std::string temp = "name";
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is GCC bug [47488](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47488), which has been resolved in GCC 9. Upgrade your compiler.

The function body is irrelevant. GCC simply couldn't deduce anything if the expression contained a string literal, so it gives up at `decltype(*beg + "name")`, which (like you correctly pointed out) should resolve simply to `std::string` when `*beg` is `std::string&`.

Comment: I am using online compiler @ https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp_online.php

Comment: Now i am using wandbox.org as you suggested and my question is: Is code snippet 1 undefined behavior since the return type and type of value returned doesn't match in the function template fcn? And so snippet 2 should be the correct way since in snippet 2 the return types and type of value returned matches? Also both snippets seems to work in wandbox.org for gcc version greater that 9 but still i am getting the old comments in red color.

Comment: Do you mean the `warning: unused parameter`? Uncheck "Warnings". There is no problem in either version. When return type is `string`, returning a `string&` will return a copy of it.

Comment: I was not talking about `warning: unused parameter` since i know its not a problem.

Comment: Okay so in the first snippet a temporary of type `std::string` initialized with `*beg` will be returned. This is like returning `std::string temp = *beg;`. Here `*beg` gives a reference to the element and whenever we use a reference it's like we are using the "referred to  object". And here the referred to object is of type `std::string`. And so snippet 1 will be perfectly okay and not undefined behavior. Is my explanation correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct, there is no UB. I'm getting no errors and no red comments [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1l2NalBRrDVLoR2G).

Comment: Yeah if we use version 10.1.0 then there are no comments in red color but if we use version 9.1.0 there are comments. It's compiler problem then. Thanks